# create multidimensional array in js from another array through a loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

Been awhile since I had to do something like this in js and having some trouble with it.

Basically I am looping looping through an array that contains ip_address, city, location, postal, and country.  A given ip_address will always have the same city, location, postal, and country values.  In my loop I want to create a new array which removes the duplicates and creates a 'total' value that keeps track of how many times that ip_address was in the results.

I have a feeling I've been working with php too much as this isn't the same, but having trouble getting what I want.  I'd like the results of `grouped` to be the ip_address values and then be able to call `grouped['ip_address']['city']` and so on to get that ip's other values.

```
    //loop through dt results and create an array of grouped ip addresses
    var grouped = [];
    dt.rows().every(function() {
        var data = this.data();             
        grouped['ip_address'] = data['ip_address'];
        grouped['ip_address']['city'] = data['city'];
        grouped['ip_address']['location'] = data['location'];
        grouped['ip_address']['postal'] = data['postal'];
        grouped['ip_address']['country'] = data['country'];
        grouped['ip_address']['total'] = grouped['ip_address']['total'] ? grouped['ip_address']['total'] + 1 : 1;
    });

    console.log(grouped);
```

example data :

```
ip_address  "111.111.111.111"
city    "Miami"
location    "Florida"
postal  "12458"
country "USA"

ip_address  "222.222.222.222"
city    "Orlando"
location    "Florida"
postal  "12423"
country "USA"

ip_address  "111.111.111.111"
city    "Miami"
location    "Florida"
postal  "12458"
country "USA"

...
```

result I would like :

```
ip_address  "111.111.111.111"
   city "Miami"
   location "Florida"
   postal   "12458"
   country  "USA"
   total  "2"

ip_address  "222.222.222.222"
   city "Orlando"
   location "Florida"
   postal   "12423"
   country  "USA"
   total   "1"

   ...
```

Comment: Please read the docs for [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), that's not what it's for. You probably want to use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: you would be better of provindg the rows structure and the output you want

Comment: Actually this is a specific function for datatables.net - it looks through the its own data.  There is no issue at all with `data` values being correct - the issue is creating `grouped` how I want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be easy

```js
//loop through dt results and create an array of grouped ip addresses
var grouped = [];
dt.rows().every(function() {
  var data = this.data();
  var item = {};
  // If the item with the same ipaddress already exist in (grouped) then append total, else push new item to (grouped).
  var foundItem = grouped.find((a) => a.ip_address == data.ip_address);
  if (foundItem)
    foundItem.total += 1;
  else {
    item.ip_address = data['ip_address'];
    item.city = data['city'];
    item.location = data['location'];
    item.postal = data['postal'];
    item.country = data['country'];
    item.total = 1;
    grouped.push(item);
  }

});
```

Comment: Yes.  This is more or less what I was originally trying to do.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want something like

```
var grouped=new Map();
dt.rows().every(function(){
  let data=this.data;
  let ip=data.ip_address;
  if(grouped.has(ip))
    grouped.get(ip).total++;
  else
    grouped.set(data.ip_address,{
      ip_address:data.ip_address,
      city:data.city,
      ...
      country:data.country,
      total:0
    });
}
```

but it's not sure, just a guess, and I can't decode the role of `total` from the question.

Comment: In the original data there can be duplicates so `total` just represents how many times the ip_address was found in the original data.  The rest of its values (city, location, etc) will always be the same given the same ip_address.

Comment: 'rows() is not iterable'.  I need to loop through the original data with `dt.rows().every(function() { var data = this.data(); ....` like I have in the post.  It's the only way to loop through its data.

Comment: @user756659 ok, it has total now and uses "every" with that strange "this.data" construct.

Comment: `let data=this.data();` and `total:1` had to be added/changed.  This will work for me.  I can do a `grouped.forEach` and run through all them like I wanted to.  The 'strange' way is just how this particular plugin was created.  It's the only way to run through its data in a loop.